# Go directly to simplexmlelement without xpath php

Tags: php, simplexml

Still very new to php...
I have a large simplexmlstring and i want to get all the lastnames from the file and in which article they where:

something like:

> article number 0 author position 0 'van Tricht'
>   article number 0 author position 1 'Nieman'
>   article number 0 author position 2 'van Tricht'
>   article number 0 author position 3 'Bour'
>   .....
>   article number 1 author position 0 'van Tricht'
>   article number 1 author position 1 'Nieman'
>   article number 1 author position 2 'van Tricht'
>   article number 1 author position 3 'Bour'

I want to go directly to `Author->LastName` but without the use of xpath, i tried it with xpath, but then my foreach loops give strange outputs... this what i tried:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
 foreach ($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) {
     $i ++;
     $j = 0;
     foreach ($xml->xpath('//Author') as $Author) {
     $j ++;
     echo $i . "articlenumber " . "author position"  . $AuthorList->Author->LastName;

       }
}
?>
```

This is the xml string:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PubmedArticle] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [MedlineCitation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Owner] => NLM
                                    [Status] => In-Process
                                )

                            [PMID] => 20538400
                            [DateCreated] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Year] => 2010
                                    [Month] => 07
                                    [Day] => 08
                                )

                            [Article] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PubModel] => Print-Electronic
                                        )

                                    [Journal] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [ISSN] => 1090-2147
                                            [JournalIssue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [CitedMedium] => Internet
                                                        )

                                                    [Volume] => 73
                                                    [Issue] => 3
                                                    [PubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Year] => 2010
                                                            [Month] => Aug
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Title] => Brain and cognition
                                            [ISOAbbreviation] => Brain Cogn
                                        )

                                    [ArticleTitle] => Increased saccadic rate during smooth pursuit eye movements in patients at Ultra High Risk for developing a psychosis.
                                    [Pagination] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [MedlinePgn] => 215-21
                                        )

                                    [Abstract] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [AbstractText] => Abnormalities in eye tracking are consistently observed in schizophrenia patients and their relatives and have been proposed as an endophenotype of the disease. The aim of this study was to investigate the performance of patients at Ultra High Risk (UHR) for developing psychosis on a task of smooth pursuit eye movement (SPEM). Forty-six UHR patients and twenty-eight age and education matched controls were assessed with a task of SPEM and psychiatric questionnaires. Our results showed that both the corrective and non-corrective saccadic rates during pursuit were higher in the UHR group. There were however no differences in smooth pursuit gain between the two groups. The saccadic rate was related to positive UHR symptoms. Our findings indicate that abnormalities in SPEM are already present in UHR patients, prior to a first psychotic episode. These abnormalities occur only in the saccadic system.
                                            [CopyrightInformation] => 2010 Elsevier Inc. All rights reserved.
                                        )

                                    [Affiliation] => Department of Psychiatry, Academic Medical Center, University of Amsterdam, The Netherlands. m.j.vantricht@amc.uva.nl
                                    [AuthorList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CompleteYN] => Y
                                                )

                                            [Author] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => van Tricht
                                                            [ForeName] => M J
                                                            [Initials] => MJ
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Nieman
                                                            [ForeName] => D H
                                                            [Initials] => DH
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Bour
                                                            [ForeName] => L J
                                                            [Initials] => LJ
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Boerée
                                                            [ForeName] => T
                                                            [Initials] => T
                                                        )

                                                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Koelman
                                                            [ForeName] => J H T M
                                                            [Initials] => JH
                                                        )

                                                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => de Haan
                                                            [ForeName] => L
                                                            [Initials] => L
                                                        )

                                                    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Linszen
                                                            [ForeName] => D H
                                                            [Initials] => DH
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Language] => eng
```

etc............

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any XML/XPath in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the desired output, your loop should look like:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) {
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($AuthorList->Author as $Author) {
        echo join(' ', array('article number', $i, 'author position', $j, $Author->LastName));
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```