# array subset php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I need to go from this simplexmlobject:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PubmedArticle] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [MedlineCitation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Owner] => NLM
                                    [Status] => In-Process
                                )

                            [PMID] => 20538400
                            [DateCreated] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Year] => 2010
                                    [Month] => 07
                                    [Day] => 08
                                )

                            [Article] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PubModel] => Print-Electronic
                                        )

                                    [Journal] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [ISSN] => 1090-2147
                                            [JournalIssue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [CitedMedium] => Internet
                                                        )

                                                    [Volume] => 73
                                                    [Issue] => 3
                                                    [PubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Year] => 2010
                                                            [Month] => Aug
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Title] => Brain and cognition
                                            [ISOAbbreviation] => Brain Cogn
                                        )

                                    [ArticleTitle] => Increased saccadic rate during smooth pursuit eye movements in patients at Ultra High Risk for developing a psychosis.
                                    [Pagination] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [MedlinePgn] => 215-21
                                        )

                                    [Abstract] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [AbstractText] => Abnormalities in eye tracking are consistently observed in schizophrenia patients and their relatives and have been proposed as an endophenotype of the disease. The aim of this study was to investigate the performance of patients at Ultra High Risk (UHR) for developing psychosis on a task of smooth pursuit eye movement (SPEM). Forty-six UHR patients and twenty-eight age and education matched controls were assessed with a task of SPEM and psychiatric questionnaires. Our results showed that both the corrective and non-corrective saccadic rates during pursuit were higher in the UHR group. There were however no differences in smooth pursuit gain between the two groups. The saccadic rate was related to positive UHR symptoms. Our findings indicate that abnormalities in SPEM are already present in UHR patients, prior to a first psychotic episode. These abnormalities occur only in the saccadic system.
                                            [CopyrightInformation] => 2010 Elsevier Inc. All rights reserved.
                                        )

                                    [Affiliation] => Department of Psychiatry, Academic Medical Center, University of Amsterdam, The Netherlands. m.j.vantricht@amc.uva.nl
                                    [AuthorList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CompleteYN] => Y
                                                )

                                            [Author] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => van Tricht
                                                            [ForeName] => M J
                                                            [Initials] => MJ
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Nieman
                                                            [ForeName] => D H
                                                            [Initials] => DH
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Bour
                                                            [ForeName] => L J
                                                            [Initials] => LJ
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Boerée
                                                            [ForeName] => T
                                                            [Initials] => T
                                                        )

                                                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Koelman
                                                            [ForeName] => J H T M
                                                            [Initials] => JH
                                                        )

                                                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => de Haan
                                                            [ForeName] => L
                                                            [Initials] => L
                                                        )

                                                    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Linszen
                                                            [ForeName] => D H
                                                            [Initials] => DH
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Language] => eng
                                    [PublicationTypeList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [PublicationType] => Journal Article
                                        )

                                    [ArticleDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [DateType] => Electronic
                                                )

                                            [Year] => 2010
                                            [Month] => 06
                                            [Day] => 09
                                        )

                                )

                            [MedlineJournalInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Country] => United States
                                    [MedlineTA] => Brain Cogn
                                    [NlmUniqueID] => 8218014
                                    [ISSNLinking] => 0278-2626
                                )

                            [CitationSubset] => IM
                        )

                    [PubmedData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [History] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [PubMedPubDate] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => received
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2009
                                                    [Month] => 10
                                                    [Day] => 26
                                                )

                                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => revised
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2010
                                                    [Month] => 4
                                                    [Day] => 28
                                                )

                                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => accepted
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2010
                                                    [Month] => 5
                                                    [Day] => 12
                                                )

                                            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => aheadofprint
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2010
                                                    [Month] => 6
                                                    [Day] => 9
                                                )

                                            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => entrez
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2010
                                                    [Month] => 6
                                                    [Day] => 12
                                                    [Hour] => 6
                                                    [Minute] => 0
                                                )

                                            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => pubmed
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2010
                                                    [Month] => 6
                                                    [Day] => 12
                                                    [Hour] => 6
                                                    [Minute] => 0
                                                )

                                            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PubStatus] => medline
                                                        )

                                                    [Year] => 2010
                                                    [Month] => 6
                                                    [Day] => 12
                                                    [Hour] => 6
                                                    [Minute] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [PublicationStatus] => ppublish
                            [ArticleIdList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [ArticleId] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => S0278-2626(10)00059-X
                                            [1] => 10.1016/j.bandc.2010.05.005
                                            [2] => 20538400
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [MedlineCitation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Owner] => NLM
                                    [Status] => MEDLINE
                                )

                            [PMID] => 19109059
                            [DateCreated] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Year] => 2009
                                    [Month] => 02
                                    [Day] => 09
                                )

                            [DateCompleted] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Year] => 2009
                                    [Month] => 04
                                    [Day] => 08
                                )

                            [Article] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PubModel] => Print-Electronic
                                        )

                                    [Journal] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [ISSN] => 1872-8952
                                            [JournalIssue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [CitedMedium] => Internet
                                                        )

                                                    [Volume] => 120
                                                    [Issue] => 2
                                                    [PubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Year] => 2009
                                                            [Month] => Feb
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Title] => Clinical neurophysiology : official journal of the International Federation of Clinical Neurophysiology
                                            [ISOAbbreviation] => Clin Neurophysiol
                                        )

                                    [ArticleTitle] => Quantification of the auditory startle reflex in children.
                                    [Pagination] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [MedlinePgn] => 424-30
                                        )

                                    [Abstract] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [AbstractText] => Array
                                                (

                                                )

                                        )


                                    [AuthorList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CompleteYN] => Y
                                                )

                                            [Author] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Bakker
                                                            [ForeName] => Mirte J
                                                            [Initials] => MJ
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Boer
                                                            [ForeName] => Frits
                                                            [Initials] => F
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => van der Meer
                                                            [ForeName] => Johan N
                                                            [Initials] => JN
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Koelman
                                                            [ForeName] => Johannes H T M
                                                            [Initials] => JH
                                                        )

                                                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Boerée
                                                            [ForeName] => Thijs
                                                            [Initials] => T
                                                        )

                                                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Bour
                                                            [ForeName] => Lo
                                                            [Initials] => L
                                                        )

                                                    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ValidYN] => Y
                                                                )

                                                            [LastName] => Tijssen
                                                            [ForeName] => Marina A J
                                                            [Initials] => MA
```

To an array that looks like:

```
Lastname  (number of times)
Boerée (2)
Koelman (2)
Bour   (2)
van Tricht (1)
Nieman  (1)
de Haan (1)
Linzen  (1)
Bakker  (1)
Boer    (1)
Tijssen (1)
van der Meer (1)
```

Regards!

First thing i need to do is get all the Last_names in one array, this should be done with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) { 
    foreach ($AuthorList->Author as $Author) { 
        //$author_last_name_list = $Author->LastName; 
        //$author_last_name_list .= $author_last_name_list; 
        $author_last_name_list join array($Author->LastName); 
    } 
}
```

(this doesn't work)

but how do i build an array in a foreach loop? 2nd if i have the big name list, how do i get a new array with "how many times the name was in the array"... Regards!

Comment: You forgot to type your question.

Comment: First thing i need to do is get all the Last_names in one array, this should be done with a foreach loop: foreach ($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) 
    {
        foreach ($AuthorList->Author as $Author)
        {
         //$author_last_name_list = $Author->LastName;
         //$author_last_name_list .= $author_last_name_list;
         $author_last_name_list join array($Author->LastName);
}
} (this doesn't work)  but how do i build an array in a foreach loop? 2nd if i have the big name list, how do i get a new array with "how many times the name was in the array"... Regards!

Comment: After the edit, it is a valid question imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples of recursive array search functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php. Just alter them to return all found instances as an array instead of only the first found match. Good luck! :)

EDIT (might as well work for it...):

I believe you can just get all `Lastname`s SimpleXML, but let's go with what you have. I think you mean something like this:

```
$author_last_name_list = array();
foreach($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) { 
    foreach ($AuthorList->Author as $Author) { 
        // $author_last_name_list join array($Author->LastName); 
        if (array_key_exists($Author, $author_last_name_list) {
            $author_last_name_list[$Author] += 1;
        } else {
            $author_last_name_list[$Author] = 1;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey, I added some code but now I see that @Felix Kling already did everything. So, good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

First, if [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450343/go-directly-to-simplexmlelement-without-xpath-php/4450810#4450810) helped you, then you should accept the answer.
If my code does not work then you should comment my answer and tell me that so that I can correct my answer.

Second, creating an array in a loop is just adding values to an empty array:

```
$authors = array();
foreach ($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) {
    foreach ($AuthorList->Author as $Author) {
        $name = (string) $Author->LastName;
        if(!array_key_exists($name, $authors)) {
            $authors[$name] = 0;
        }
        $authors[$name] += 1;
    }
}
```

And later loop over `$authors`. The keys contain the name and the value the occurrences.

**update:** *(because I'm nice this time ;))*

```
foreach($authors as $name=>$times) {
    echo $name . "($times)" . "<br />"; // or PHP_EOL if you print it on a terminal
}
```

Read more about [*arrays in PHP*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

---

Regarding your code: Even if it does not work, a short remark:

```
$author_last_name_list = $Author->LastName; 
$author_last_name_list .= $author_last_name_list;
```

With this, you are first setting the variable `$author_last_name_list` to `$Author->LastName`, overriding the value that was in `$author_last_name_list` before, and then you concatenate. What you will always get is:

```
$author_last_name_list = "A";
$author_last_name_list .= $author_last_name_list; // => 'AA';
```

*If* you want to get the names in a string (which does not help you here anyway) then you would have to initialize the variable *before* the loop:

```
$author_last_name_list = '';
foreach($xml->xpath('//AuthorList') as $AuthorList) { 
    foreach ($AuthorList->Author as $Author) { 
        $author_last_name_list .= $Author->LastName; 
    } 
}
```

And

```
$author_last_name_list join array($Author->LastName);
```

is not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: Thank you very very much... 1. How do I 'accept your answer' is there a sumbit button for that? (sorry very new here) 2. I can see the logic in the code! But it doesn't work... I get this error: Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The first argument should be either a string or an integer in /var/www/phptest/get_lastnames.php on line 24... So it saying that there should be a string in the variable, i checked and there is a string...?

Comment: @Thijs: 1. There is a tick on the left side of an answer (just below the vote counter). Click it to accept the answer. You should do that for your other questions too! (if they they have a working answer). 2. You get the error because `$name` is not a string. It is still a `SimpleXMLElement`. It just gets converted to a string when you print it. See my updated answer (you have to cast it to a string).

Comment: I "is answered" the previous questions, thanks for the explanation... I have this almost working, now when i echo, $Authors i get "Array" how do i display the content of this array? THANKS!!!

Comment: @Thijs: By using a `foreach` loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php (btw. not that I care so much, but why did you accept the other answer and not mine here? ;))

Comment: Does this function makes an array with 2 dimension? I need the name and the number of times the name has occured...

Comment: @Thijs: Honestly: Learn more PHP before you use it. Arrays are the only and therefore most important datastructure in PHP. Read the documentation. On the page I linked to, it is written: *foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)* so you can loop over an array, and access an items key with `$key` and the value with `$value`. have a look at the examples. And it is not a 2 dimensional array. Just a normal associative array. the names are the keys and the values are the occurrences as i described in my answer. have a look at my update.

Comment: I am learning PHP, i know... I already got the foreach loop to displays the array, but i needed to have the name beside 'm but i will get there, i shall read more on the basics! Thank you very much for your time and patience!!

Comment: @Thijs: No worries, don't take me too serious, sometimes I can be a bit harsh (and impatient, but I'm working on that), but I don't mean to :) But seriously: The PHP documentation is very good, so make use of it. It has a lot of examples. Happy coding!

Comment: I figured it out! I did alot of LabVIEW programming, so this a bit new for me... foreach ($authors as $lastnames => $key)
{
echo $key . " "  .$lastnames . "<br />";
}  Anyway a lot of thanks!!!